# Arbitrary number of entries in a column in SQLITE

Tags: database-design, schema

It's been a while since I used SQL, and I'm having trouble coming up with the best schema for the table(s) in my database.

Ultimately, I have a bunch users (primary key) which each have a number of attributes that I'm keeping track of. One of these attributes is a set of groups to which they belong (think of the way blog posts have tags - multiple posts can share the same tag, and the same tag can have multiple posts).

What is the best way to construct the table(s) for this database so that I can easily check the groups associated with a user, and also the users who belong to a given group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, there's only 0 or 1 entry per column, no more. (Arguably, Null is an entry, so in that sense there really is always 1 entry per column). When you're thinking of having several entries in a column, it's time to break down the model.

Start with your basic data elements, forget about how they relate with each other:

```
User
-----
ID
Name
```

```
Group
----------
ID
Description
```

Then link the two:

```
UserGroup
----------
UserID
GroupID
```

The other "single" attributes that the user could have (e-mail address, url, age, whatever) would go in the User table.

Example:

```
User: ID = 1, Name = John
User: ID = 2, Name = Mary
Group: ID = 1, Description = Boys
Group: ID = 2, Description = Students
Group: ID = 3, Description = Programmers
UserGroup: UserID = 1, GroupID = 1  -> John is a member of "Boys"
UserGroup: UserID = 1, GroupID = 2  -> John is also a member of "Students"
UserGroup: UserID = 2, GroupID = 2  -> Mary is another member of "Students"
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused - how would a user be associated with multiple groups, then? It seems that the UserGroup table still only has one GroupID element.

Comment: @thebackhand: several entries can be made into UserGroup. We can say there is no uniqueness constraint (or that it's on a UserID-GroupID pair). I'm going to append my answer with an example.